# postfix header_checks fails for no reason with ! (not operator)

Tags: pcre, regex-lookarounds, postfix-mta

Why does regular expression `!` doesn't work?

In my `header_checks` file I got

```
!/^Subject:.*NotBot.*/ REJECT fuck off
```

In my master.cf I use the cleanup daemon for checking

```
cleanup  unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
  -o header_checks=pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

when I connect to stmpd via telnet to test (Good Subject) I get this

```
220 test.com ESMTP Postfix
HELO www.test.com
MAIL From: <test@test.com>
RCPT To: <test@test.com>
DATA
From: <tester@hahaha.com>
Subject: NotBot123

test250 test.com
250 2.1.0 Ok
250 2.1.5 Ok
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>

.
550 5.7.1 fuck off
```

But Bad Subject's also work

```
220 example.com ESMTP Postfix
HELO www.example.com
MAIL From: <test@test.com>
RCPT To: <test@test.com>
DATA
From: <tester@hahaha.com>
Subject: hahaha

test250 test.com
250 2.1.0 Ok

250 2.1.5 Ok
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
.
550 5.7.1 fuck off
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it! was pretty easy..

the check_headers is checked for every information in the mail.. so you need to use `if/endif` to check only `Subject:` field.

```
if /^Subject:/
!/^Subject:.*NotBot.*/ REJECT fuck off
endif
```

Dumb spammers suspended my email account due to abusing my open stmp port.